# Bootbox JS - Alert to use "Close"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

We use the Bootboxjs.com project for bootstrap.

We need to change the text of the bootbox.Alert('DDDD") box that appears. The documentation didn't show how to.

Anyone know how to change the text of the Alert button?

Comment: Do You would like to change the OK/Cancel ?

Comment: Yes, right now it is "Ok" they want it "Close"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a dialog:

```
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "I am a custom dialog",
  buttons: {
     success: {
      label: "Close",
     }
  }
})
```